# Adding current time to SQLite database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-database

I have made a database todo list application and would like to add the current time to it. However, I do not know how to do this in Java.

```
public void addProduct(ListItem product) {
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(COLUMN_TODO, product.getToDo());
  values.put(COLUMN_FOR, product.getAccFor());
  SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
  db.insert(TABLE_LIST, null, values);
  db.close();
}
```

This is my current function to add an object to the database:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_LIST = "List";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TODO = "ToDo";
public static final String COLUMN_FOR = "accFor";
private String University = "University";
private String Work = "Work";
private String Personal = "Personal";
```

And these are the variables I declare at the start of the database, if it is possible using Android Studio I would like to also add the current time into the database so it can be displayed alongside the other values, GPS would be nice also, however, I feel this may be a little advanced.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIST + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_TODO + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FOR + " TEXT " +
            ");";
  db.execSQL(query);
}
```

This is the code for creation of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `long currentTime = new Date().getTime` and this is the current time in milliseconds ([see documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime())). And then just add this long value to your database.

If you want to convert this time back to a date object, just call `new Date(yourLongValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column for time, then update it using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time"  as a variable? or would it be int?   values.put(COLUMN_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis()); and it would insert like this?

Comment: You need to update your database schema and add a new column for time with type "long"